# centos install java openjdk for jenkins

Tags: centos, java, jenkins

I have an issue with a VPS, centos, thats running WHM as the container. I need to run open-jdk to get jenkins ci going, but the issue is that oracle's java keeps popping up. From a server restart:

```
root@host [~]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01, mixed mode)
```

and my system:

```
root@host [~]# cat /etc/*release*
cat: /etc/lsb-release.d: Is a directory
CentOS release 5.9 (Final)
```

My $PATH points to `/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/us...` which is where oracle java is located. So my quick-fix solution is to add the openjdk to `/etc/profile` and call `source /etc/profile` at every restart. This is what I've added to `/etc/profile`:

```
#as per: http://www.24k.com.sg/blog-29.html
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.19.x86_64
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar
export PATH JAVA_HOME CLASSPATH
export PATH=${PATH/\/usr\/local\/jdk\/bin:}
#end as per
```

Now `java -version` returns the openjdk, but `javac -version` is not found!:

```
root@host [~]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_19"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.9.1.el5_9-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
root@host [~]# javac -version
-bash: javac: command not found
```

Also even though `java -version` returns open jdk when I look at the csf access logs I can see that jenkins is still calling the oracle jdk.

```
root@host [~]# service jenkins reload
Shutting down Jenkins                                      [  OK  ]
Starting Jenkins                                           [  OK  ]
```

csf ldf log, notice that its still calling oracle java `/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_37`:

```
May 17 07:32:30 host lfd[4392]: *User Processing* PID:4324 Kill:0 User:jenkins VM:802(MB) EXE:/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_37/bin/java CMD:/usr/local/jdk/bin/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/jenkins/tmp -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=8009 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20 --prefix=/jenkins --accessLoggerClassName=winstone.accesslog.SimpleAccessLogger --simpleAccessLogger.format=combined --simpleAccessLogger.file=/var/log/jenkins/access_log
```

Getting open-jdk working with jenkins is step one for getting this issue solved... https://serverfault.com/questions/507885/cant-install-jenkins-on-centos#comment571671_507885
any help would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have installed java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.
If you still can't don't have to javac in the path, then use  update-alternatives to configure it:

```
 # update-alternatives --config javac
```

In case of java7 link is missing, add it:

```
 # update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/javac 1
```

Comment: cheers for the your help...
the java*-devel package wasn't installed, i've installed it now but the problem still persists. `java -version` gives `java version "1.6.0_37"` and `javac -version` gives `javac 1.6.0_37`. If I run `source /etc/profile` then (see op) the `/usr/local/jdk/bin:` is removed from my $PATH. But server restart puts `/usr/local/jdk/bin:` back. Also there is no option for the sun-jdk in update-alternatives and update-alternatives always says that open-jdk is set

Comment: you can enforce different java by defining JENKINS_JAVA_CMD in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins